# Problem with Maven execution after installation

Tags: symbolic-link, maven-3

when i run **mvn -v** i get the below error:

> **`bash: /usr/local/apache-maven/apache-maven-3.3.1/bin/mvn: No such file or directory`**

At /usr/local/ there was a apache-maven directory and i deleted it. And i deleted the symlink pointed to the mvn in bin directory of apache-maven-3.3.1.

I have extracted apache-maven-3.3.3 directory at /usr/local/.
I have edited the /etc/environment file to include the Maven related environment variables and PATH. Here is my environment file.

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/local/apache-maven-3.3.3/bin"
JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle"
M2_HOME="/usr/local/apache-maven-3.3.3"
M2="/usr/local/apache-maven-3.3.3/bin"
MAVEN_OPTS="-Xms256m -Xmx512m"
```

So i have clearly included in the PATH, /usr/local/apache-maven-3.3.3/bin where mvn executable exists.

**which mvn** returned this

> **`/usr/local/apache-maven-3.3.3/bin/mvn`**

What am i missing..? I'm a novice for Linux environment.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue.

```
type mvn
mvn is aliased to `/usr/local/apache-maven/apache-maven-3.3.1/bin/mvn'
```

that means there has been a alias created for mvn. this was further assured by

```
$alias
alias alert='notify-send --urgency=low -i "$([ $? = 0 ] && echo terminal || echo error)" "$(history|tail -n1|sed -e '\''s/^\s*[0-9]\+\s*//;s/[;&|]\s*alert$//'\'')"'
alias egrep='egrep --color=auto'
alias fgrep='fgrep --color=auto'
alias grep='grep --color=auto'
alias l='ls -CF'
alias la='ls -A'
alias ll='ls -alF'
alias ls='ls --color=auto'
alias mvn='/usr/local/apache-maven/apache-maven-3.3.1/bin/mvn'
```

I removed the alias by

```
unalias mvn
```

Now it works!